# Doctrine won't join two columns- Using Symfony2 and Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have two tables:

Posts

id | title | content | user

---

Users

id | name

---

and I want to have user name in Posts collection. What am I doing wrong here? Do I have to write custom query to do this?

Right now I'm getting user's id in posts collection.

```
class Posts
{

...

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="user", type="text", length=250)
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Users", inversedBy="posts")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
protected $user;

...
```

User class:

```
class Users
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", length=250)
     */
    public $name;
    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Posts", mappedBy="user")
    */
    protected $posts;

   ...
```

Comment: Have you specifed oneToMany relation in User class ?

Comment: done - user class added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have an error in your $user relation annotation, you can't make a column be a regular @ORM\Column AND a @ORM\JoinColumn, try:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Users", inversedBy="posts")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $user;
```

this will give you the entity(referencedColumnName must be primary key), then you can do $user->getName();

Comment: Yeah, that works, but it is pulling all user columns from Users table. Is there a way to pull only name?

Comment: You would need to write a custom query.